# Why my PHP files not executing on Nginx server

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, symfony, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have a Nginx web server and I have this project. I want to execute the index.php but it downloads rather than executing it.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name your_domain.com www.your_domain.com;

    root /var/www/nerdowallet_backend/public;
    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

That is my conf file

I want to execute this index.php file than downloading it

Comment: You did restart the nginx service after changing the configuration, didn't you? Anything you see in the error log file?

Comment: no errors in the error.log

Comment: And you are also sure you are not looking at an earlier result that has been cached on the client side?

Comment: I am using `fastcgi_pass php-fpm;` ...

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files. Check that the `server` block appears correctly. The `server` block posted in your question should not be able to download `index.php`.